# PHP Built in server thinks port is not available, however netstat disagrees

Tags: php, symfony, jenkins, gruntjs

I have a jenkins build job of my symfony2 project that uses grunt to start the php built in webserver so that casperjs can run functional tests against it.

To start my webserver I'm using the following command:

```
php app/console server:start --router=" + __dirname + "/app/config/router_test.php --env=test 0.0.0.0:9001"
```

However the build fails with the following message:

```
A process is already listening on http://0.0.0.0:9001.
```

Thus I have SSHed to the jenkins box and run:

```
netstat -tln | grep 9001
```

Only to get no results?!

I have restarted the server and killed all php processes, disabled iptables however none of this seems to work.

This build used to work and in the last change, all that was added were more functional tests.

Has anyone got any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: I have fixed this by changing my workspace directory in jenkins. Therefore it looks like a permissions issue. I'm happy that my build is working again, not so happy that I don't know the exact reason that it wasen't before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the fix that worked for me was to change the workspace directory. Seems to have been a permissions issue with the workspace folder that jenkins created yet a chmod 777 didn't resolve it hence the new workspace folder.